# Unable to locate element within an iframe through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm new to Selenium. I'm trying to write a Python script that will log in to a particular form. The form is located at http://www.tvta.ca/securedContent

The code I'm running is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://tvta.ca/securedContent/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("txtUserName")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("<<my email>>")
```

I get an error that says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="txtUserName"]
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here? I've checked the source of the webpage the login field is definitely named txtUserName.

Comment: Emphasis mine: **http**://tvta.ca/ **securedContent** / Probably... not a good sign.

Comment: Need to switch into frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch to the frame to write text in the textbox, try to check syntax once as I have less in good in Python

```py
framLogin= driver.find_element_by_id("membeeLoginIF")
driver.switch_to.frame(framLogin)
EmailTxt = driver.find_element_by_name("txtUserName")
EmailTxt.send_Keys("Test@gmail.com")
```

Same in Java

```java
WebElement framLogin= driver.findElement(By.id("membeeLoginIF"));
driver.switchTo().frame(framLogin);
WebElement EmailTxt = driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName"));
EmailTxt.sendKeys("Test@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

That site requires third-party cookies to be enabled; without them, the login form does not load. It's likely you have your browser configured that way but the defaults for `webdriver.Firefox` do not.

To see what Selenium is actually seeing, dump `driver.page_source` and/or take a screenshot with `driver.save_screenshot(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

The desired element is within an `<iframe>`. So as per *best practices* you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired frame to be available and switch to it.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"membeeLoginIF")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.textboxWaterMark#txtUserName"))).send_keys("Jeff")
  ```
- You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```